# Splitting string by two conditions in vb.net 2014

Tags: vb.net, string

I'm trying to split a string into a list of strings with this vb.net code, while adding it to a dictionary of String:

```
objevt.wbStr.Add(b, objevt.metalbelowwidth.Item(b).Split({",","-"}).ToList)
```

But I get an error saying "Value of '1-dimentitional arrary of string' cannot be converted to 'Char' "

If I try to implement splitting with just the comma, it works fine. So the following code works. 
    objevt.wbStr.Add(b, objevt.metalbelowwidth.Item(b).Split(",").ToList)

But I really want to split the string with two conditions. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

One of the overloads of the [`Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) Method that takes a String array also needs to have a [`StringSplitOption`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringsplitoptions%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) parameter also set.

```
objevt.wbStr.Add(b, objevt.metalbelowwidth.Item(b).Split(New String() {",", "-"}, StringSplitOptions.None).ToList)


Sub Main()
    Dim myString As String = "H,c,J-Hello-World"
    Dim myList As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)
    myList = myString.Split(New String() {"-", ","}, StringSplitOptions.None).ToList
    For Each s As String In myList
        Console.WriteLine(s)
    Next
    Console.ReadLine()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the overloaded `Split` method with an array of `char` as the separators, like so:

```
objevt.metalbelowwidth.Item(b).Split(New [Char]() {","c, "-"c })
```

Demo [here](http://rextester.com/CMNV96425)